# Delete specific rownumbers in .csv file using java

Tags: java, excel, csv

For ex: I am trying search a text with name "abc"in .csv file which is present in column no 6 in multiple rows and I need to delete those rows.

I tried below code. I am able to get the line no/row no where  text "abc" is present in column 6 but it is not deleting the rows.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class ReadExcel {

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception{

        String csvFile = "csv filelocation";

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        List<String[]> allElements = reader.readAll();

        String [] nextLine;
        int lineNumber = 0;
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            lineNumber++;

           if(nextLine[5].equalsIgnoreCase("abc")){
            System.out.println("Line # " + lineNumber);

            allElements.remove(lineNumber);



        }


        }
```

Comment: where you have lines.add(nextLine), if you just do lines.split(",") you'll have all the values in the line... Then what are you doing with the values once you have them?

Comment: Better use a proper library that handles everything like quotes and multiline values etc., like [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html).

Comment: Actually I want to store all the cells in an array and read them one by one.

Comment: I a now trying to delete the rows, but unable to delete.

Answer (score 0):

For reading the files in CSV format, I am currently using the library [**super-csv**](https://github.com/super-csv/super-csv). There are various examples.

Let me know if you need help to use it.

Comment: I need to download the specific library for using super-csv I guess. And will it read the input cell by cell

Comment: Yes! Are you using Maven?

Comment: I am now trying to delete the rows, but unable to delete.

Comment: Do you want to delete a row from the file or from the list/set in memory?

Comment: I want to delete all the rows from the file where the user criteria meets

Comment: I suggest you clear the entire content's file and write only the lines that are under your criteria

Comment: No i want to clear those lines and save it into new csv file.

Comment: Ok! At the end, it is the same. So you have only to use the **CSVWriter**, where is the problem?

Comment: Can you please provide me the code how to use csvwriter

Answer (score 0):

So, if you would like to use the [**opencsv**](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) library, I start a new example for writing the new content in a CSV file. I take inspiration from your example code.

```
List<String[]> allElements; /* This list will contain the lines that cover your criteria */ 

/*
...
*/

CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"));
writer.writeAll(allElements);
writer.close();
```